# Ubuntu Server + lightdm + VNC != usbale Desktop. Don't know what i did wrong

Tags: server, lightdm, vnc

I'm using ubuntu server 20.04 to run a standalone system, which hosts my automated tasks and zigbee gateway.

The Zigbee gayteway uses software from "phoscon / deconz" [https://www.dresden-elektronik.de/funk/software/deconz.html]

This software can run headless and provides a basic web-site for managing the devices, but as soon as you need to go deeper or debug anything (and this is the point i am currently at) you need to run this software with a gui.

As there is no other way, i installed lightdm and x11vnc (with all dependences needed) and did a minimal config, as several tutorial mention.

Just a note on the side: i was wondering, why after installing lightdm i wasn't able to reach my "server" anymore after a while. I didn't know lightdm forces the host to go in sleep mode after a few minutes. I followed another hint, which said to do
`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`
I hope this will fix this.

But for now i have another problem:

When i finally start x11vnc i see a login screen and when i log in with my credentials, i see just the desktop background. No menu, no taskbar, nothing ...
According to this, when i start the deconz software with gui (and see in the terminal it is running), i see no GUI over vnc.

I think i did something wrong, but i don't even know where to start searching for the error ...

Comment: You mention installing a DM and x11vnc, and whilst you mention desktop/GUI many times, did not mention what GUI/desktop you actually installed. What DE or desktop are you trying to use?

Comment: while installation of lightdm it gave me the choice of gdm3 and lxde. I took lxde because i wanted to use minimal resources for this and later on, after debugging deconz, i would prevent the GUI from starting anyways

Comment: If you don't need a *local* GUI then I'd suggest starting over and using a standalone VNC server such as tightvncserver or tigervncserver rather than a DM + desktop + x11vnc (which is really intended for relaying a "physical" desktop)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. tightvnc still not worked "out of box", but way easier to get it running and finally got a GUI over vnc and could debug the suftware successfully.